# Constructor must be called super error in JSP, JDBC, servlet and forms

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc, registration

I'm creating a registration form for my web application and I'm getting the following error when I try to access register a new user:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: eBooks/Data/UserDB, method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this() java.lang.VerifyError: (class: eBooks/Data/UserDB, method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()
at eBooks.controller.RegisterUserServlet.doPost(RegisterUserServlet.java:62)
```

This is the UserDB class:

```
package eBooks.Data;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


import eBooks.business.User;
import eBooks.util.DBUtil;


public class UserDB {

    public static int insert(User user)
    {

        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

         String query = 
                "INSERT INTO User (fName, lName, email_address, password, dataOfBirth, phone,"
                + " address, city,  state,  country,  zipcode, accountType)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

         try
         {
             ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
             ps.setString(1, user.getfName());
             ps.setString(2, user.getlName());
             ps.setString(3, user.getEmailAddress());
             ps.setString(4, user.getPassword());
             ps.setString(5, user.getDateOfBirth());
             ps.setString(5, user.getPhone());
             ps.setString(6, user.getAddress());
             ps.setString(7, user.getCity());
             ps.setString(8, user.getCountry());
             ps.setString(9, user.getState());
             ps.setString(10, user.getZipcode());
             //ps.setString(11, user.getAccountType()); -- Ask Jassin 

             return ps.executeUpdate();

         }
         catch(SQLException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return 0;
         }
         finally
         {
             DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
             pool.freeConnection(connection);
         }

    }


    public static int update(User user)
    {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        String query = "UPDATE User SET" 
                        + "fName = ?"
                        + "lName = ?"
                        + "password = ?"
                        + "dateOfBirth = ?"
                        + "phone = ?"
                        + "address = ?"
                        + "city = ?"
                        + "state_or_Region = ?"
                        + "country = ?"
                        + "zip = ?"
                        + ""
                        + "WHERE email_address= ?";   

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, user.getfName());
            ps.setString(2, user.getlName());
            ps.setString(3, user.getEmailAddress());
            ps.setString(4, user.getPassword());
            ps.setString(5, user.getDateOfBirth());
            ps.setString(5, user.getPhone());
            ps.setString(6, user.getAddress());
            ps.setString(7, user.getCity());
            ps.setString(8, user.getCountry());
            ps.setString(9, user.getState());
            ps.setString(10, user.getZipcode());
             //ps.setString(11, user.getAccountType()); -- Ask Jassin 

            return ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }

    }


    public static int delete(User user)
    {
       ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
       Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement ps = null;

       String query = "DELETE FROM User" +
                      "WHERE email_address = ?";
       try
       {
           ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
           ps.setString(1, user.getEmailAddress());

           return ps.executeUpdate();

       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return 0;
       }
       finally
       {
           DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
           pool.freeConnection(connection);
       }
    }



    public static boolean emailExists(String emailAddress)
    {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT email_address FROM User"+
                       "WHERE email_address = ?";


        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, emailAddress);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            return rs.next();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;            
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }
    }

    public static User selectUser(String emailAddress)
    {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM  User"+
                       "WHERE email_address = ?";

        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, emailAddress);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            User user = null;
            if (rs.next())
            {
                user = new User();
                user.setfName(rs.getString("fName"));
                user.setlName(rs.getString("lName"));
                user.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("emailAddress"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                user.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                user.setDateOfBirth(rs.getString("dateOfBirth"));
                user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                user.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
                user.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
                user.setState(rs.getString("state"));
                user.setZipcode(rs.getString("zip"));
                // user.setAccountType(rs.getString("accountType")); -- Ask Jassin
            }
            return user;            
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the RegisterUserServlet:

```
package eBooks.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

import eBooks.business.User;
import eBooks.business.Account;
import eBooks.Data.UserDB;


public class RegisterUserServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
                       throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lName");
        String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String dateOfBirth = request.getParameter("dateOfBirth");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phohe");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String state = request.getParameter("country");
        String accountType = request.getParameter("accountType");
        //TO DO: Account acctTypeList = request.getParameter("acctTypeList");  add this an object first

        User user = new User();

        user.setfName(fName);
        user.setlName(lName);
        user.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
        user.setAddress(address);
        user.setCity(city);
        user.setCountry(country);
        user.setState(state);
        user.setZipcode(phone);

        //TODO: user.setAccountType(accTypeList); -- Ask Jassin


        // Add information to the database

        if(UserDB.emailExists(emailAddress))
            UserDB.update(user);
        else
            UserDB.update(user);

        session.setAttribute("User", user);

        Cookie emailCookie = new Cookie("emailCookie", emailAddress);
        emailCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*2);
        emailCookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(emailCookie);

        String url = "WEB-INF/view/registration_confirmation.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    }


}
```

I'm new to web development and I just need a push in the right direction to fix this issue.

I'm using glassfish and mysql.

Comment: This error actually suggests there's a bug in the compiler you're using! What are you using to turn your `*.java` files into `*.class` files?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill thanks for the response. I'm using Netbeans 7.1, with no frameworks

Comment: Just fixed the problem – moved all the files to a new project and manually created the web.xml and it's is working fine now. Thanks @ErnestFriedman-Hill

Comment: So maybe you had a corrupted class file. Glad you're up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed the problem – moved all the files to a new project and manually created the web.xml and it's is working fine now. Thanks @ErnestFriedman-Hill